# Jquery Mouseclick Stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseclick-event, onmouseclick

My issue at the moment is that I have a function that takes ~600ms to complete. If a user spam clicks the selector it invokes multiple calls. I have tried to stop spam clicking by disabling the click event callback when the function is called, however, this does not work. Is there any way to stop mouseclicks or remove queued callbacks.

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    $(this).off('click.disabled');
    //DO STUFF
    $(this).on('click.disabled', false);
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: And what does this function look like, is it asynchronous etc ?

Comment: Isn't everything in Javascript asynchronous as its only run on one thread? Apologies if I am wrong, fairly new to JS and am extremely tired ^.^

Comment: Display a spinner or something while it's running, maybe that will keep the users from spam-clicking.

Answer (score 0):

Can use boolean to get state :

```
var clicked = false;
$('.selector').click(function() {
    if (!clicked){
        clicked = true;
        ...
        clicked = false;
    }
});
```

or use "one" method to attach handler only once

```
var myFunc = function(){
    ...


   //on finish 
   $('.selector').one( "click", myFunc);
};

$('.selector').one( "click", myFunc);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. Events are queued, so subsequent click handlers don't run until the previous one finishes, so the variable will always be `false`.

Comment: If that were what was happening, his original code would work.

Comment: Both methods unfortunately still call the function once the current one is complete.

Comment: what are you doing in your method that takes 600ms ?

Comment: Drawing to four different canvases then converting those canveses to dataurls.

Answer (score 0):

```
var clickTime = -1;

$('.selector').click(function() {
    if (clickTime == -1) {
        clickTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    var end = new Date().getTime();
    var time = end - clickTime;
    if (!$(this).hasClass('selected') && time < 500){
        e.addClass("selected");
        // Do other stuff
        clickTime = new Date().getTime();
       }
});
```

I'm going to use this for now. Will most likely need to do more research on event calls and figure a different way to prevent this as I do not like my hacky solution.

Any feedback would be much appreciated regardless.